# Strange behaviour with HTTP Headers with curl on MacOS vs. ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, macos, curl, asp.net-web-api2

I've run into a really strange problem today and regardless I finally found the solution, looking for some explanation of what's been happening here.

I have a controller in ASP.Net Web API 2 and I have to check a HTTP header value, see these two snippets:

```
IEnumerable<string> requestClientIds;
var hasClientId = Request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-ClientId", out requestClientIds);
if (hasClientId)
{
    var clientId = requestClientIds.FirstOrDefault();
    // Do something with client ID value here
}
```

And:

```
var clientIdHeader = Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "X-ClientId");
if (clientIdHeader.Value != null)
{
    var clientId = clientIdHeader.Value.FirstOrDefault();
    // Do something with client ID value here
}
```

These codes essentially do the same in my understanding, and both versions work perfectly with an API client (tried with Postman) or with curl on both Windows and Mac OS.

However, there's one exception: the second snippet cannot read the X-ClientID header's value if the API endpoint is called from Mac OS with curl over https! In that case, the X-ClientID header doesn't have a value. It works even on MacOS, with curl, over plain http.

Here's how I tried with curl:

```
curl -H "X-ClientId: TEST" --request GET "https://path.to/my/api/endpoint"
```

Any ideas on why the second approach fails with MacOS - curl - https?

Comment: maybe case sensitiveness?

Comment: Absolutely! I just wrote further tests right after I posted my question and realized that my custom headers are converted to all lowercase from OSX when firing the request with curl. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: And what did you do to fix it?

Comment: I fixed the backend code so it now looks for the header in a case-insensitive way.

Answer (score 0):

As r1verside pointed out, it was a case sensitivity issue. Apparently, curl on OSX converts all provided header values to lowercase if the request goes over https - therefore the FirstOrDefault method won't find the header.